# Как различать input text?

Tags: php, ajax, post, form

Есть таблица учета товара где есть возможность продать товар в нужном количестве.
Проблема в том что `input type text` с одинаковыми классами и именами. Есть возможность их различать?
`<input type="text" value="0" name="count"  class="count-value" size="1"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="count"  class="count-value" size="1"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="count"  class="count-value" size="1"/>`
ajax:
`$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit-stat").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {count: $('.count-value').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result-block').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="count[]"  class="count-value" size="1"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="count[]"  class="count-value" size="1"/>
<input type="text" value="0" name="count[]"  class="count-value" size="1"/>
```

Таким образом можно передавать массив

Answer (score 0):

Можешь добавить id, например

```
<input id="one" type="text" и т.д.>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде

$('.count-value') возвращает список элементов класса count-value

.val() возвращает значение 1 элемента в списке.

А если вы хотите обратиться например ко второму элементу, но селекторами его не выбрать, то можно использовать функцию eq. eq возвращает элемент списка по номеру. Нумерация начинается с 0.

Получаем

```
$('.count-value').eq(0).val() - значение первого input'а
$('.count-value').eq(1).val() - значение второго input'а
$('.count-value').eq(2).val() - значение третьего input'а
```